# Regex. Help needed

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will extract complete path to a file from a string that looks like:

```
c:\DevProjects\Web Projects\RD_deploy\obj\Release\Source\App_Code\BusinessLogic\WebMethodTypes\WebCompressionResult.cs(33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CompressionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

or

```
c:\DevProjects\AssaultRifle.cs(157): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Gunpowder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
^(.*)\([0-9]+\):.*$
```

This should do it.

Comment: I cant't do split... I need a match.

Comment: this is a match.  In perl you could do: $file = $1 if /^(.*)\([0-9]+\):.*$/

Answer (score 2):

`^([^\(]+)`

This will get the beginning of the string, up to the first `(`, into group 1; in your case, the whole path up to `(33)...`.

edit:
If you might have parentheses in your filenames, things get a bit more complicated.

`^(.+)(\(\d+\)):` will match everything up to a parenthesized number followed by a colon, like "(33):" or "(157):", into group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
([a-zA-Z]:(?:\\\\\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)+\.\w+)
```